# Query does not display full data

Tags: sql, string, mariadb, aggregate-functions

I suppose I have a problem with query or... I dont know.
The query does not display all the text.
I dont have any error.

Please check my query. I can't fix it.
Maybe do you have idea?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, you have hit the maximum number of characters allowed by `group_concat()`, which is controlled by system variable [`group_concat_max_len`](https://mariadb.com/docs/reference/mdb/system-variables/group_concat_max_len/). It defaults to 1 MB starting MariaDB 10.2.4, and 1K in earlier versions.

You can change the default setting for the current session with:

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 5000000; -- or whatever value you like
```

The maximum allowed value is `18446744073709551615`.